# Moving certain cells between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file where I need to take the dates out of the sheet named "Simulator Data" and place them into a sheet named "Consolidated Data" using VBA. The dates in "Simulator Data" start in the 7th row and then appear again every 31 rows after that in columns D, E, and F (year, month, day in separate columns), and I want to move them to "Consolidated Data" starting in row 1 with step=10 and in columns B, C, and D.

I have been able to find some code, but when I try to run it all it does is copy the last date in the "Simulator Data" into every tenth row in "Consolidated Data". The code I have only focuses on the year cells that is why it is going from D in "Simulator Data" to B in "Consolidated Data". What changes do I need to make so that it will work?

Here is my code

```
Sub consolidate()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Simulation Data").Range("B65356").End(xlUp).row

Dim srow As Long
Dim crow As Long
For srow = 7 To lastrow Step 31
    For crow = 1 To lastrow Step 10
        Sheets("Consolidated Data").Range("B" & crow) = Sheets("Simulation Data").Cells(srow, "D")
    Next crow
Next srow

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. That does not help. Include the actual code in your question so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: ^ [Edit] the question.

Comment: I don't think that `Value.Copy` makes sense since the value of a cell is not itself a range object. In any event -- why *copy* the value rather than just assigning that value to the value of the destination cell? Unless you need to copy formats, there is seldom a good reason to use `.Copy` on a cell-by-cell level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you really want that nested loop?

```
Sub consolidate()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim srow As Long
    Dim crow As Long
    Dim wsSim As Worksheet, wsCons As Worksheet

    Set wsSim = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Simulation Data")
    Set wsCons = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated Data")
    lastrow = wsSim.Range("B65356").End(xlUp).Row

    crow = 1             '<< destination start row
    For srow = 7 To lastrow Step 31
        wsSim.Cells(srow, "D").Resize(1, 3).Copy wsCons.Range("B" & crow)
        crow = crow + 10 '<< increment destination row
    Next srow

End Sub
```